# Mobile Images in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Our carousel looks great on Desktop but when we view it on a mobile device, the images are small and not taking the entire width of the screen. Is there anyway to make the images take up the entire width of the screen or close to it or any updates to the code?

Code for carousel is as follows:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
<a href="retaillocations.html"><img src="images/bangles.jpg" width = "100%" class="img-responsive"
```

Please view at www.brownmanclothing.com

Comment: this looks like spam to me. It is also off topic here. Please view the Help Center for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try by reducing the padding of the body that is pushing the content and the slider.

```
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

to

```
@media(min-width:768px) { 
    body {
        padding: 70px;
    }
}
```

Also you could try putting the #carousel-example-generic in

`<div class="row">
      <div id="carousel...
 </div>`

Comment: Thank you idoliki. We will try this.

Comment: The below code helped with the sizing of the carousel. It made it bigger. But it pushed the carousel images into the nav bar and extended the contend beyond the screen of the phone. 


@media(min-width:768px) { 
    body {
        padding: 70px;
    }
}

Comment: You could put `@media(min-width:768px) { body { padding: 70px; padding-top: 120px;} }`
`@media(min-width:992px) { body { padding-top: 60px } }`

Comment: Thanks @idoliki. Not sure why but when I paste your code it, it still pushes the carousel into the nav bar even if I adjust the padding. Am I doing something wrong? I found the below code and found that it works:                                                                                                          body {
padding: 30px;
padding-top: 60px;
}